# ipython cd magic does not seem to be working properly in Windows

Tags: windows, ipython

I'm noticing some strangeness with how paths work in IPython. I'm using version 1.2.1 but I've seen the problem in 1.1 as well. The first thing I notice is that the %pwd and the %cd magics give different results. If I use os.getcwd(), I see that the %cd macro seems to be right. Can anyone explain why this is occurring?

```
%pwd
Out[1]: u'C:\\Users\\bubnabm1\\Documents\\Python Scripts'

%cd
C:\emacs

import os

os.getcwd()
Out[4]: 'C:\\emacs'
```

The second (probably related) issue I'm noticing is that when I use the %cd magic to change my path it prints the new path to stdout, and os.getcwd() shows the path has changed, but if I call %cd again it prints the old path as if nothing has changed. Is there something I'm missing here? Continuing from my previous example, the code sample below shows this behavior:

```
%cd ..
C:
os.getcwd()
Out[6]: 'C:\\'

%cd
C:\emacs
```

I've looked at StackOverflow, Google, and the IPython issue tracker and haven't found anything that could explain this behavior. However I'm a new IPython user and I'm open to the possibility that I'm misunderstanding something or doing something incorrect, so I wanted to post here before I raise the issue to the IPython team. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `%cd` without an argument usually changes to your home directory. Usually on Windows that's `C:\Users\foo`, but if it thinks `C:\emacs` is your home directory for some reason, what you show would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

IPython's %cd magic, like its other shell-like magic commands (pwd, ls), is modeled on Linux, not on Windows.

In Windows, a cd command without arguments acts like the Linux pwd - it prints the working directory. You were apparently expecting this behavior from IPython's %cd magic. But in Linux/OSX/*nix, a cd command without arguments changes the working directory to your home directory.